# Schengen visa - Duration of stay Extension - Approach

Tags: schengen-visas, spain, overstaying, visa-extensions

I applied for Schengen visa thru Germany embassy for travel from 10th August to 24th August, staying maximum days in Germany (5). I got my visa for duration of stay as 15 days (same as itinerary). Some plans have changed at my end and I may plan to Visit Spain as well as part of the trip with Spain being the maximum stay duration. Can i apply for another Schengen visa at Spain embassy giving the exact reasons so that my effective duration of stay covers the next 7 days? OR do I have to request the German embassy for duration of stay extension?

Answer (score 1):

Once (correctly) issued, a Schengen short-stay visa **cannot be extended** except in situations of *force majeure* (natural disaster, sudden illness, strikes etc) that physically prevent you from leaving the Schengen Area within the limits.

The way to do what you want to is to apply for **another visa** that will cover your additional visit in Spain. Since Spain is the main destination for the extra validity period you should file that with the *Spanish* consulate in your country of residence.

Comment: Thanks, Henning. Just to confirm, what happens if my German visa validity is beyond the initial trip (September 3rd)? In this situation will Spain consulate issue an overlapping Schengen visa?

Comment: @Jiyeshmehta: Hmm, that's a good question. They might end up deciding that the clearest way forward is to revoke the German visa and instead issue a single visa that is good for the entire journey, but it shouldn't be up to you to guess the right bureaucratic form. In your position I would document the entire trip in the new application, and state very clearly that you would be okay with _replacing_ the German visa with a single combined one.